# Desktop effects/graphics settings probably get reset after each reboot

Tags: permissions, kde, graphics

I am using PC Linux OS, full monty(KDE) and probably after an update, I have started experiencing the following behavior:

After each reboot, the Kresource migrate tool starts up, even though Akonadi is disabled. Also(and thats the important issue), the graphics performance is pretty ugly. It is so slow, I can even see the frames updating.

But the interesting thing, is that when I am changing a setting to, say, Desktop Effects menu and then revert it back, everything is back to the expected performance.

I believe it is related to some permission issue and the related configuration can be applied by the system, but I dont know the internals very well, so any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue on OpenSUSE 13.2 with KDE.  I set full repaint in desktop effects, and when I reboot, that doesn't work even though it is still set.  When I change a setting, save it, revert it, save it, then it works fine.